# How can I specify a value must have a specific type without creating a variable for it?

Tags: typescript, styled-components, emotion

Say I have

```
type TypeMsAnimationDuration =
  | 75
  | 100
  | 150
  | 200
  | 250
  | 300
  | 350
  | 500;

const cssInJs = css`transition: all ${999}ms;`
```

How do I ensure that value '999' is a value of TypeMsAnimationDuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without putting it in a variable or creating a helper function that you have to call to validate the value :

```
type TypeMsAnimationDuration =
| 75
| 100
| 150
| 200
| 250
| 300
| 350
| 500;

function animDuration(ms: TypeMsAnimationDuration) {
    return ms;
}
const cssInJs = css`transition: all ${animDuration(999)}ms;` // Error
const cssInJs = css`transition: all ${animDuration(250)}ms;` // Ok
```

Comment: Yeah, I made the exact same function - I just thought it odd to have a function do nothing but return the same value and I thought surely TypeScript had another way to do it.

I believe with Flow you could just do it like this:
`const cssInJs = css\`transition: all ${999: TypeMsAnimationDuration}ms;\``

Comment: Somewhat similar, but you could also try an arrow function: `const cssInJs = (ms: TypeMsAnimationDuration) => { return css\`transition: all ${ms}ms;\` }` and use it like `cssInJs(999) // Error`